# ghc does not work because of missing "Rts.h"

Tags: linux, haskell, gcc, ghc, mageia

When I try to compile a Haskell program using ghc, it always raises the same exception: (translated to English)

```
$ ghc vtzr.hs
Linking vtzr ...

/tmp/ghc8101_0/ghc8101_0.c:1:17:
     fatal Error: Rts.h: File or directory not found
Compilation aborted.
```

Actually, the "Rts.h" is located properly at /usr/lib64/ghc-7.4.2/include so I do not really understand what the compiler complains about. I examined it a little further and found out that the exception actually comes from gcc trying to compile a tmp-file which includes Rts.h:

```
*** C Compiler:
'/usr/bin/gcc' '-fno-stack-protector' '-Wl,--hash-size=31' '-Wl,--reduce-memory-overheads' '-c' '/tmp/ghc8656_0/ghc8656_0.c' '-o' '/tmp/ghc8656_0/ghc8656_0.o' '-DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE' '-I' '-I/usr/lib64/ghc-7.4.2/include'
```

I am using ghc 7.4.2 and gcc 4.7.2 on Mageia 3 Linux x86_64. Maybe it is just a Mageia issue...? BTW. Running the program with runghc works fine.

Comment: While I can't help you with the real problem here, I'd like to suggest you can just prefix your failing command line with `LANG=C`, which produces error messages in English which may produce better results on search engines than the localized ones.

Comment: Where did you get this copy of GHC?  I suggest you try one of the binaries built by GHCHQ.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this seems to be either a problem with the Mageia version of ghc or a ghc 7.4.2 bug which is fixed in the recent release: I just built a ghc 7.6.3 from source and it works fine.